# Python Error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DataReader'

Tags: python, finance, datareader, pandas-datareader

I am learning from a book called "Learn Algorithmic Trading" by Donadio and Ghosh, and I literally copy-and-pasted the code directly from the book:

```
from pandas_datareader import data

# Fetch daily data for 4 years, for 7 major currency pairs
TRADING_INSTRAMENT = 'CADUSD=X'
SYMBOLS = ['AUDUSD=X', 'GBPUSD=X', 'CADUSD=X', 'CHFUSD=X', 'EURUSD=X', 'JPNUSD=X', 'NZDUSD=X']
START_DATE = '2014-01-01'
END_DATE = '2018-01-01'

# DataSeries for each currency
symbols_data = {}
for symbol in SYMBOLS:
    SRC_DATA_FILENAME = symbol + '_data.pkl'

    try:
        data = pd.read_pickle(SRC_DATA_FILENAME)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        data = data.DataReader(symbol, 'yahoo', START_DATE, END_DATE)
        data.to_pickle(SRC_DATA_FILENAME)

    symbols_data[symbol] = data
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cinji/PycharmProjects/LearnAlgorithmicTrading/StatArb.py", line 16, in <module>
    data = pd.read_pickle(SRC_DATA_FILENAME)
  File "C:\Users\cinji\PycharmProjects\LearnAlgorithmicTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 170, in read_pickle
    f, fh = get_handle(fp_or_buf, "rb", compression=compression, is_text=False)
  File "C:\Users\cinji\PycharmProjects\LearnAlgorithmicTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 434, in get_handle
    f = open(path_or_buf, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'GBPUSD=X_data.pkl'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cinji/PycharmProjects/LearnAlgorithmicTrading/StatArb.py", line 18, in <module>
    data = data.DataReader(symbol, 'yahoo', START_DATE, END_DATE)
  File "C:\Users\cinji\PycharmProjects\LearnAlgorithmicTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5274, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DataReader'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I run the file that came with the purchase of the book, the same error is produced.  I googled and checked for solutions, but have not found one.

I have also checked Yahoo in case it changed the symbol for currency, but it doesn't look like any changes have been made.

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: You're importing the datareader module as `data`, but then you're also declaring a local variable named `data`, which overwrites the imported module.  Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks!  I renamed the local variable and it worked.  It's disheartening when we find these errors in books that are meant to educate people.